# Google Leaderboard display broken in latest release? (Google Play Services 7.5.71)

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I had been successfully using the following code to launch the Google Leaderboards display from my game:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(googleApiClient,getString(R.string.leaderboard)),LEADERBOARD_REQUEST_CODE);
```

However, recently after updating including Google Play Services (and probably other google libraries), the leaderboard display no longer launches and instead I get the return code `GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED` in `onActivityResult`(), and in the logcat I see:

```
E/ClientUiFragAct(26401): Not signed in. To launch Client UI activities, you must be connected to the games service AND signed in.
```

even though when I attempt to launch the GUI, I check I am signed in by doing `googleAPIClient.isConnected()` which returns true.

So, on 2 separate devices, this functionality has stopped working on the same version of my app when the only relevant change I can think of has been updates to Google libraries (Google Play Services 7.5.71 1955121-036).
I have a third device on which it still works, with an older version of Google Play Services 6.7.76 (1745988-034).
I build using API level 22.

Curiously, a couple of other games (not mine) still have Google Leaderboard display working with version 7.5.71 installed.

I may be barking up the wrong tree with the Google Play Services version hypothesis.

Anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

We solved the issue by removing the "setAccountName" call in the configuration of the GoogleApiClient.Builder.
Old code:

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this );  
builder.addApi( Games.API );  
builder.addScope( Games.SCOPE_GAMES );  
builder.addConnectionCallbacks( this );  
builder.addOnConnectionFailedListener( this );  
builder.setAccountName( "some.account@gmail.com" );  
builder.build();
```

New code:

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this );  
builder.addApi( Games.API );  
builder.addScope( Games.SCOPE_GAMES );  
builder.addConnectionCallbacks( this );  
builder.addOnConnectionFailedListener( this );  
builder.build();
```

This has the drawback that the account chooser will be shown when signing in which is okay in our use case and maybe yours as well. At least the achievements screen can be opened again.